# Clear EditText focus and hide keyboard when Clicked or Touched another Views

Tags: android, android-edittext

I try to hide keyboard and clear cursor(also can't type something).

I'm making an app with edittext, FrameLayout(it's just container) and textView(having clickListener). When I enter something into edittext and then touch or click another views, I want hide keyboard(shown) and clear focus on edittext(appearing cursor).

here is my code.

MainAcitivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout mainLayout;

    EditText editText;
    FrameLayout container;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                Log.d("onFocusChange", "b #" + b);
                // i can only get true, i can't get false value. how can i get false value.
                // i want to use this method so hard!
            }
        });


        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // hide Keyboard and editText's focus will be false(also cursor is going to hide).
            }
        });

        container = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                // hide Keyboard and editText's focus will be false(also cursor is going to hide).
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and

activity_main.xml (this is just simple layout having EditText, frameLayout and TextView)

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"

    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"

        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"

        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"

        android:gravity="center"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="textView : layout_alignParentBottom = true"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

last thing, AndroidManifest.xml

i just insert code : `<activity ... android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">  ... </activity>`

Comment: textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   textView.requestFocus(); add above 2 condition in textview click listener

Comment: it works!.(i can get false value from editText's focusChangeListener) but, 
container.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); container.requestFocus(); its not works.

Comment: ok then use container.onclicklistener and then check

Comment: i appreciate your solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `final` at `editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);`

try this

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
});
```

or

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }

        }
});
```

I hope this is helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

You have to listenthe onFocusChange of editText

Code can be like this.

```
 editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.editText && !hasFocus) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

                }
            }
        });
```

This code will work even  if you have a swipe with fragment.(For Fragment change mContext to getActivity());

Comment: oh, i needed this code, working on fragment. mwah! :D